# Get all entries for this month only

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to get a count of all my Offer entries for this month. At the moment I use this to make the count:

```
@offer_count = Offers.find_all_by_accepted(false).count
```

This works fine, but as you can see it does count all my entries. So my question is how can I change this to only get the count of the entries of this month.

Also I would like to have the possibility to duplicate this and find all my Offers of an specific month. Like get all offers with accepted false and created in January.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`beginning_of_month`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_month) to compare the date against:

```
Order.where('created_at >= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_month)
```

You could of course substitute `created_at` for `updated_at` if that's what you want. You can also add on more `where` conditions if you need (e.g. `.where(:accepted => false)`, as you seem to need in your question).